# Is it possible to query resource properties?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the Firestore security rules you can access [resource properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#resource_1). I would like to use these properties in my queries, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Currently I am manually writing `updatedAt` timestamps into documents where I need them, but that is cumbersome and fragile, because it is easy to forget to update the timestamp. It also feels redundant, since the resource already has this data.

Is it, for example, possible to query all documents in a collection that have been updated since yesterday?

Comment: "since the resource already has this data" --> Have in mind that the data of the resource from the link you provided has been manually added when creating that document... To query all documents in a collection that have been updated since yesterday, you'd need to get today's date and do it minus 1 day in the programming language you're using. Then query it on Firestore using something like `collectionRef.where("updatedAt", ">=", yesterday)`

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes To me, the documentation is suggesting that there are implicit document metadata values outside the ones you define for yourself, such as __ name __, __ createdAt __, etc.

Comment: I've just re-read the documentation. You're right. It does provide metadata values. @DougStevenson

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes The OP is suggesting that the metadata values are not well documented, and I tend to agree.  I created a bug internally to reflect the questions that came up for me when reading this.

Comment: @DougStevenson Exactly. I can't find anything besides [this on SnapshotMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata), but that doesn't say anything about the timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to query on these, they are specific to the Security Rules layer.

While we can inspect the server update time for a specific document once retrieved, we cannot query for them since it is not indexed (and handled at a layer lower than our indexing engine).

Comment: Bummer. I think it would be helpful if it was made possible to add these resource timestamp fields to a manually created index. But being able to read them has at least some value to me. Where is this documented? The [docs about document snapshot metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata) doesn't tell me much